# PostgreSQL: Is there a way to insert into multiple tables at once in order to satisfy RLS policies?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, row-level-security

I have tables that represent relationships between different persons (legal and natural) by membership. The typical case being people being members of organizations. So, I did this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE
  person (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    modified_at timestamp with time zone,
    card jsonb -- this contains the details in JSON inspired by vCard, e.g. '{ "fn": "Full Name", "url":"http://my.site.org/" }
  );

CREATE TABLE
  member (
    organization uuid references person (id) on delete cascade not null,
    member uuid references person (id) on delete cascade not null,
    begin timestamp with time zone DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'utc'),
    "end" timestamp with time zone,
    primary key (organization, member)
  );
```

I am using RLS and I want to allow a user to insert a `person` into any `organization` they have write-permission to. For that, I have an SQL function `can()` that gives me all the organizations (`person` row IDs) they may write to. So, I wrote the following policy:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "Person can be created in organization with write-permission." ON person
  FOR INSERT WITH CHECK ( 
    EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM member WHERE can('write') ? organization::text AND member = id ) 
  );
```

My question: In order to fulfill this policy, I need to simultaneously insert the new `person` and the corresponding `member` link. Is this even possible?

I tried both

```sql
WITH new_member AS ( 
  INSERT INTO member (organization, member) 
    VALUES ( 'cb00aaa9-4c95-4f1a-862e-21406d4d10e0', gen_random_uuid() ) 
    RETURNING member ) 
INSERT INTO person ( id, card ) 
  SELECT member, '{"fn":"Coherent Insert?"}' 
  FROM new_member;
```

and

```
WITH new_person as ( 
  INSERT INTO person (id, card) 
    VALUES (gen_random_uuid(), '{"fn":"Coherent Insert?"}') 
    RETURNING id ) 
INSERT INTO member ( organization, member ) 
  SELECT 'cb00aaa9-4c95-4f1a-862e-21406d4d10e0', id from new_person;
```

but both complain about:

```
ERROR:  new row violates row-level security policy for table "person"
```

I could of course put both inserts into a `SECURITY definer` function without RLS and check privileges manually there but I am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: I don't understand the `AND member = id` part of the policy. I think you want to allow inserting *any* (existing) person into one of the organisations that the current user can write to?

Comment: Oh wait that's a policy on `person` which checks for existence of membership. I thought the policy for "*inserting a person **into** an organization*" would be a policy on the `member` table. There you'd only check the organisation being writable for the current user. Creating persons (that may be unrelated to organisations) would be a separate thing then, and it seems you would not like that?

Comment: With the one policy that you have, you'd need to create the `member`ship first, the person second. This should be possible by **deferring** the foreign key constraint.

Comment: I guess a `SECURITY definer` function might still be the easiest and most straightforward solution though; especially if you also want to put policies on the `member` table that that prevent users from adding (existing) persons as members of arbitrary organisations

Comment: OK, maybe to be more specific: I want to avoid that users can insert "dangling" persons that are not associated to any organization (that they control).

Comment: @Bergi How can I defer the foreign-key constraint?

Comment: You'd [create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtable.html) or [alter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertable.html) the constraints to be `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, or as `DEFERRABLE` only and then [set them to be deferred](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set-constraints.html) during your transaction.

Comment: I had this same problem, one solution is to use two different statements in `plpgsql` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454654/row-level-security-with-common-table-expression?noredirect=1#comment136548938_77454654