# Row Level Security with Common Table Expression

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, supabase, row-level-security

Given this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  title text NOT NULL CHECK (char_length(title) > 2),
  author uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT auth.uid() REFERENCES profiles(id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  content text NOT NULL CHECK (char_length(content) > 3),
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  name text,
  pid uuid REFERENCES posts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  PRIMARY KEY (name, pid)
);

CREATE POLICY "rls_tags_read_public"
  ON tags FOR SELECT
  USING (true);

CREATE POLICY "rls_tags_create_authenticated_own_posts"
  ON tags FOR INSERT TO "authenticated"
  WITH CHECK (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM posts p WHERE p.author = auth.uid() 
    AND p.id = pid
  ));
```

I'm trying to insert a post using:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_post(
  title text,
  content text,
  tags text[]
)
RETURNS SETOF posts
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  WITH new_post AS (
    INSERT INTO posts (title, content)
    VALUES (title, content)
    RETURNING *
  ),
  insert_tags AS (
    INSERT INTO tags (name, pid)
    SELECT unnest(insert_post.tags), id FROM new_post
  )
  SELECT * FROM new_post;
$$;
```

However, I get:

```
'new row violates row-level security policy for table "tags"'
```

If I get rid of the RLS policy, it seems to work.

I also am able to change the langauge to `plpgsql` without CTE, and it seems to work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_post(
  title text,
  content text,
  tags text[]
)
RETURNS SETOF posts
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  new_post posts%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO posts (title, content)
  VALUES (title, content)
  RETURNING * INTO new_post;

  INSERT INTO tags (name, pid)
  SELECT unnest(tags), new_post.id;

  RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = new_post.id;
END;
$$;
```

I want to write up some more complicated transactions, but I need to use `sql` and `CTE` for other purposes.

Does RLS not work with CTE transactions?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you're using RLS in this situation - it looks like you're trying to (ab)use RLS as some kind of cross-table constraint...

Comment: Also, you need to explicitly enable RLS with `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY` - but your post doesn't show that.

Comment: RLS is enabled. I'm not sure how using RLS referring to another table is abuse?

Comment: It's abuse because a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint does the exact same thing, with minimal performance cost (assuming it's indexed). I'm actually surprised Postgres even allows cross-table references like this...

Comment: @dai - I actually relooked at my table. The reason I am checking the foreign key is to confirm it is the same table that contains the post author Id.  Hence, you can't add a tag unless you are adding it to a post, and you are the author of that post.  My problem persists where I can't use langauge sql for this to work.

Comment: Why not add an `author` column to `tags`?

Comment: So you recommend denormalization only in this case? That may be the only way anyway, as it seems CTEs are evaluated independently of each other. That I believe is my real problem.

Comment: I don't consider the approach used in my answer as a denormalization; composite-keys aren't considered a denormalization because it conveys nonredundant information in the form of ownership semantics; plus, if you change your business-rules to eventually allow people other than the `post`'s author to add tags to it then it definitely isn't a denormalization.

Comment: @dai - I thought about this more, this wouldn't work, as you would be the author of the tag, but not necessarily the author of the post. I need to enforce the only person allowed to add a tag to the post, is the author of the post (other logic later for admins, editors).

Answer (score 2):

> I actually relooked at my table. The reason I am checking the foreign key is to confirm it is the same table that contains the post author Id. Hence, you can't add a tag unless you are adding it to a post, and you are the author of that post. My problem persists where I can't use langauge sql for this to work.

That's what composite *secondary-keys* (aka `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`) indexes are for.

Like so:

- Also...

  - No-one should be using cryptic column names like `pid`, [or ambiguous names like `id`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16616/why-do-people-recommend-not-using-the-name-id-for-an-identity-column))
  - Your PKs should be immutable. Having `DELETE CASCADE` is fine, but `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not.
  - You appear to be using Supabase's `auth.uid()` extension - I don't recommend this because it means introducing a hard dependency between your storage-layer and your application-code layer - this means that you won't be able to easily manually edit data in the database using other tooling unless you're careful to disable all `DEFAULT` constraints referencing Supabase extensions.
  - Your `tags.name` and `tags.post_id` columns are missing explicit `NOT NULL` constraints. While the columns are implicitly `NOT NULL` because they're part of the `PRIMARY KEY` if you were to ever change the PK definition you'll need to add the `NOT NULL` to your db-schema-in-source-control otherwise a redeployment will see them having `NULL`able columns (and you *are* keeping your db-schema in source-control, right?)
  - The first column of a composite-key should always be the most selective: one would assume `tags.post_id` is going to be more selective than `tags.name`, so `post_id` should go first.
  - Consider getting into the habit of aligning your `CREATE TABLE` statements's parts into columns, it makes them significantly more readable:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  post_id        uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  title          text        NOT NULL CHECK ( char_length( title ) > 2 ),
  author_user_id uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT auth.uid() REFERENCES profiles( user_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  content        text        NOT NULL CHECK ( char_length( content ) > 3 ),
  created_at     timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),

  CONSTRAINT PK_posts PRIMARY KEY ( post_id ),
  
  CONSTRAINT UK_posts_author UNIQUE ( post_id, author_user_id ) /* Referenced by tags.FK_tags_posts */
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  name           text        NOT NULL,
  post_id        uuid        NOT NULL,
  created_at     timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  author_user_id uuid        NOT NULL DEFAULT auth.uid() REFERENCES profiles( user_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE,

  CONSTRAINT PK_tags PRIMARY KEY ( post_id, name ),
  
  CONSTRAINT FK_tags_posts FOREIGN KEY ( post_id, author_user_id ) REFERENCES posts ( post_id, author_user_id ) /* This will use `UK_posts_author` */
);
```

Comment: Yes I have read the Supabase issues with Kysley, Drizzle, Prisma, etc, but I plan on sticking with Supabase only and maximizing every feature. Thanks for all the tips here, lots of great insight!